# How to use different System.assertEquals() in two separate methods?

Tags: apex, unit-test, datetime

I have the following test methods.
Test method #1:

```
public static List<Account> testAccountsMethod1() {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        for (Account account : accounts) {

            AccountCalculateTime calculateStartTime = new AccountCalculateTime();
            calculateStartTime.calculateStartHours(account);

            System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 10, 43, 2), account.CreatedDate);
            System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 13, 43, 2), account.CompletedDate);
        }

        insert accounts;
}
```

and
 Test method #2:

```
public static List<Account> testAccountsMethod2() {

        List<Account> accountsList = new List<Account>();

        for (Account account : accountsList) {

            Datetime createdDate = account.CreatedDate;
            Datetime completedDate = account.CompletedDate;
            AccountCalculateTime calculateEndTime = new AccountCalculateTime();
            Double calculatedEndHours = calculateEndTime.calculateEndHours(createdDate, completedDate);

            System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 10, 43, 2), createdDate);
            System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 13, 43, 2), completedDate);
        }

        insert accountsList;
}
```

How to make assertion for the hours to be different, because the assertion for Test method #1 is the same as the assertion for Test method #2.

In the `calculateEndHours()` are passed two parameters `createdDate` and `completeDatetime`.

Method `calculateEndHours()` is returns Double.

I need an assertion for `calculatedEndHours`.

Please advise and share an example.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to test. The DateTime is static, so your test will fail since your creation time will never match the static value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these test methods makes sense. They need to be reconsidered, rather than simply adding an assertion. Let me try to show why that's the case.

### First Method

```
public static List<Account> testAccountsMethod1() {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        for (Account account : accounts) {
```

Execution will never enter this loop because `accounts` is empty. Presumably you mean to either create new sObjects in memory, or query a list of Accounts that have been created and inserted in your `@testSetup` method, which is where you should create common test data that is shared by all of your test cases.

```
            AccountCalculateTime calculateStartTime = new AccountCalculateTime();
            calculateStartTime.calculateStartHours(account);
```

This will never get called, per above.

```
            System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 10, 43, 2), account.CreatedDate);
            System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 13, 43, 2), account.CompletedDate);
```

These assertions are of little value. Asserting your Account's CreatedDate is valueless, because it cannot be affected in any way by the code you are testing.

Additionally, there is no field `CompletedDate` on Account. If this is a custom field, it must be `CompletedDate__c`. It's not clear how or whether `calculateStartHours()` makes changes to the Account to populate that field.

Fundamentally, these assertions should be focused on demonstrating that whatever work `calculateStartHours()` does is completed and completed correctly. If that method calculates something based on the input Account, you need to

- make sure it is called with a real Account record that you create, whose field values are designed to cause `calculateStartHours()` to perform its work. Note that you may need to call the method several times with different inputs to execute all of its different logical paths.
- Make assertions to validate that the results are what you expect based on the designed input values.
- You do not need, in general, to make assertions about the input data that you create. These would be tautological.

  ```
      }

      insert accounts;
  ```

This does nothing, because the list is empty. Were it not empty, the insertion should typically happen *before* invoking any test code that reads records from the database. There's no point calling it at the end of the test method.

```
}
```

### Second Method

```
public static List<Account> testAccountsMethod2() {

    List<Account> accountsList = new List<Account>();

    for (Account account : accountsList) {
```

Again, execution will never enter this list.

```
        Datetime createdDate = account.CreatedDate;
        Datetime completedDate = account.CompletedDate;



        AccountCalculateTime calculateEndTime = new AccountCalculateTime();
        Double calculatedEndHours = calculateEndTime.calculateEndHours(createdDate, completedDate);

        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 10, 43, 2), createdDate);
        System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstance(2017, 6, 10, 13, 43, 2), completedDate);
```

As above, these assertions prove nothing at all about *what `calculateEndHours()` does*. You need to be making an assertion about the value of `calculatedEndHours` that would show that it's calculated correctly based on the input values.

Since this method takes two DateTime values as inputs, you don't really need to create Accounts at all. You can test this method by creating DateTimes, passing them to the method, and then asserting that the correct Double is returned.

```
    }

    insert accountsList;
```

As with the first method, this has no effect on the test and can be removed.